# pptx issues with fonts size and color from procedure

Tags: python, procedure, python-pptx

ive created a code to create PPT presentation from a dataframe. defined a procedure "addtext" to add text passing some parameters. somehow, procedure is ignoring text size and color .. why ?  thanks!

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
prs = Presentation()
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'titolo': ['Pizza Margherita', 'Bolognese', 'Fish and Chips', 'Tacos', 'Sushi', 'Paella', 'Spaghetti Carbonara', 'Couscous', 'Falafel', 'Goulash'],
    'commenti': ['pomodoro, mozzarella, basilico', 'pomodoro, carne macinata, carote, sedano, cipolla', 'pesce fritto, patatine fritte', 'carne, cipolle, peperoni, pomodoro, avocado', 'riso, pesce crudo, alga nori', 'riso, pollo, gamberi, verdure', 'uova, pancetta, pecorino romano', 'couscous, agnello, verdure', 'fagioli, cipolle, spezie', 'carne, paprika, patate'],
    'numero': [8, 12, 10, 9, 15, 20, 14, 18, 6, 16],
    'paese': ['Italia', 'Italia', 'Regno Unito', 'Messico', 'Giappone', 'Spagna', 'Italia', 'Marocco', 'Medio Oriente', 'Ungheria']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def addtext(titlee,L,T,SS,RR,GG,BB):
    txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(Inches(L),Inches(T),Inches(1),Inches(1))
    tf = txBox.text_frame
    p = tf.paragraphs[0]
    run = p.add_run()
    run.text = titlee
    font.name = 'Calibri'
    font.size = Pt(SS)
    font.color.rgb = RGBColor(RR,GG,BB)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)
    
    addtext(row['titolo'],.2,1,42,0, 0, 255)
    addtext(row['commenti'],.2,2,22,102, 255, 102)
    addtext('Costo medio: ' + str(row['numero']) + ' €',.2,5,18,32, 32, 255)

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't associated the `font` variable with the run (variable `run`).